# Java 3d ArrayList subMatrix modification alters other subMatrices of the 3d ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I am relatively new to Java and am running into an issue. I have a 3d `ArrayList` and I send an item of this `ArrayList` to a method where it is modified. But this seems to alter other items of the 3d `ArrayList`.

So I create a matrix `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>>` and print out each item.

```
for(int i =0; i<solutionsMatrix.size(); i++)
{
    //System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(solutionsMatrix.get(i));
}
```

I then send this 3d `ArrayList` to another method. Where each subMatrix (i) is modified. But when doing this somehow the modification of a matrix (i) also alters other (non-i) matrices.

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> siftSolutions(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>> solutionsMatrix)
{
    for(int n=0; n<solutionsMatrix.size();n++){
    //System.out.println(solutionsMatrix.get(n));
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> currentMatrix = mirrorMatrix(solutionsMatrix.get(n));
    System.out.println(currentMatrix);
}
```

The issue is that the printed out matrix (commented out portion in second code block) does not match the printed out matrix of the first code block. I have fiddled with the code and determined that the method `mirrorMatrix` is somehow altering the 3d matrix `solutionsMatrix`.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mirrorMatrix(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> unmirrored) {
    //every value of ij needs to equal ji, thus simply transmit all non-zeros
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mirror = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(unmirrored);
    for (int i = 0; i < mirror.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < mirror.size(); j++) {
            if (mirror.get(i).get(j) != 0) {
                mirror.get(j).set(i, mirror.get(i).get(j));
            }
        }
    }
    return mirror;
}
```

I have tried searching for an answer online but I could not find an explanation (which may simply be a result that I do not know the proper terminology to describe my problem well). I hope someone can explain to me why this is occurring so I can resolve the issue and avoid it in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mirror = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(unmirrored);
```

This line does not make a deep copy of all the elements in it. It does create a new instance of an `ArrayList`, but all its the elements are the same instances of `ArrayList<Integer>` as were present in the `unmirrored` instance.

So changing those elements with `mirror.get(j).set(i, mirror.get(i).get(j));` does change the same instance `mirror.get(j)` and `unmirrored.get(j)`. I.e., `mirror.get(j) == unmirrored.get(j)`.

Comment: Oh I did not know that. So hypothetically, if my larger 3d Matrix was constructed of subMatrices that were generated in the same way as above. (I did not include that but they were generated by recursively trying different combinations). A modification to one subMatrix could alter another subMatrix in the 3d Matrix because they are not deep copies?